# PHP:- validate and pass the value by POST in newtab

Tags: javascript, php, html

Below code is about passing the value to the new tab by POST.

**My question is the value selected in drop-down list needed to be validated.**

As 'select' value is default value. If the default value is selected then some alert must be shown else the remaining behavior is same as below code.

```
<form action="send_mail.php" name="choose_aff" method="POST">
<select name="company" id="company" class="company_select" style="width:250px;">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="abc">abc</option>
<option value="xyz">xyz</option>
</select>
<input class="proceed_btn" type="submit" value="Proceed to mail>>" style="float:right" onclick="this.form.target='_blank';return true;">
</form>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code attempts? Are you using just plain vanilla javascript, or a library like jQuery?

Comment: I'm new in php, html, javascript, jquery. So i don't know much. Please suggest me what is vanilla. which are other types and how i can do better development using all above languages

Comment: It seems like you want to validate the form before it is submitted.. I would suggest using something like JValidate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remove a button and then the send_mail.php will open only when value is changed from dropdown. Add dropdown will send value using POST

```
<form action="send_mail.php" name="choose_aff" method="POST">
    <select name="company" id="company" class="company_select" style="width:250px;" onchange="submit()">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="abc">abc</option>
    <option value="xyz">xyz</option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can validate without external libraries, just using javascript in client side (if you want) You need something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myValidateFunction() {
    alert("something happened!");
    console.log("something happened!");
    //what i want!
  }
</script>
...
<form action="send_mail.php" name="choose_aff" method="POST" target="_blank"> 
    <select name="company" id="company" class="company_select" style="width:250px;" onchange="myValidateFunction()">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="abc">abc</option>
        <option value="xyz">xyz</option>
    </select>
<input class="proceed_btn" type="submit" value="Proceed to mail" style="float:right;" />
</form>
```

Then you should validate the data sent in send_mail.php file

Answer (score 0):

Add `target="_blank"` to form attributes like this

```
<form action="send_mail.php" name="choose_aff" method="POST" target="_blank">
```

Comment: the new tab and redirection of my code is also working. The problem is validation. After validating only new tab must open.

Comment: try using "onsubmit" for validation